# How do I write a Delete SQL Statement in Java for Tables with composite key?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm 99% this question has been answered somewhere, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. So far, I've been writing my sql statement to delete a row from a table in java like this (this for a table called crime where the primary key is called CrimeId. The CrimeId is taken from the UI)

```
private DatabaseAPI db;
PreparedStatement st=db.connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM crime WHERE CrimeId = '"+Integer.parseInt(txtCrimeId.getText())+"';");
```

How would I write the where statement for a composite key? Like, for a table called charges in which the key is both CrimeID and CriminalID?

Comment: Use a `where` clause with `and` to combine multiple constraints. Why are you using prepared statements if you still concatenate values instead of binding them?

Answer (score 1):

Something like below:

```
PreparedStatement st=db.connection.prepareStatement(
  "DELETE FROM crime WHERE CrimeId = ? AND CriminalID = ?" );
st.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(txtCrimeId.getText() );
st.setInt( 2, Integer.parseInt(txtCriminaId.getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe next code should work for you

```
PreparedStatement st=db.connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM crime WHERE CrimeId = ? and CriminalID = ?");
st.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(txtCrimeId.getText()));
st.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(txtCriminalID.getText()));
st.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM charges WHERE CrimeId = '____' AND CriminalID = '____' ;
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AND`. With `AND` you combine to conditions.

> Read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) for more information

So then your code looks like

```
DELETE FROM charges WHERE CrimeId = 'YourCrimeID' AND CriminalID = 'YourCriminalID' ;
```

Just replace `YourCriminalID` and `YourCrimeID`.